# Udev symlink is changing data

Tags: usb, udev, symbolic-link

I have a udev rule that identifies a Spektrum RC dongle and symlinks its hidraw file to a custom one. This is the udev rule I am using.

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0483", ATTRS{idProduct}=="572b", SYMLINK+="spek"
```

The symlink is created successfully and I can cat the /dev/spek file. However, the data inside the file appears to be different from the data coming from the raw file.

To describe the differences first you may need to know the default behaviour that happens in the hidraw file:

If there is no changing to the input (i.e. not moving the sticks) on the RC Controller, the RC Dongle emits a constant stream of exactly the same data out, representing the state of the Controller. When the sticks are moved on the controller, this data stream changes to match the state of the controller. There is never a break or pause in the incoming data.

However in the symlink file, there is no constant stream of data. It only updates that file when the sticks are moved on the controller, which would change the data in the source file. In addition to that, it also seems that the data that gets fed through to the symlink file is entirely incorrect.

The raw data from the raw hidraw file follows a set format that can be parsed, the data coming from the symlink appears to be garbage.

Is there something I can do to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to specify to use the hidraw subsystem, otherwise the symlink went to some random file. So the final rule was

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0483", ATTRS{idProduct}=="572b", SYMLINK+="spek"
```